# Why does the map only work on my emulator and not a real device?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

Very new to this but I can only get my maps api to work on my emulator. Whenever I use the app on a real device the map just stays blank. Also I have to retype in the api key into my local properties file every time I open the project from github so potentially this has something to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

The map may appear blank on a real device for various reasons. I suggest connecting the real device to your computer and checking the Logcat for more detailed error messages.

If you encounter error messages in Logcat like the following:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.
> Check that `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your APIkey"/>`
> is in the  element of AndroidManifest.xml

Possible root causes of this error include:

The signing key or the package name of your APK that you installed on the real device is different from the one you registered on the Google Cloud.

**To resolve this issue, check your signing key and package name on Google Cloud, and ensure they are consistent.**

The `local.properties` file is typically added to the `.gitignore`, preventing it from being included in your Git repository. Hence, you need to retype the key into the `local.properties` file each time you pull your code from GitHub.